# Function that returns the factors of a number into an empty array

Tags: javascript

I have an assignment that requires me to find if the sum of the factors of a number minus the number itself is equal to the number. I have written the function below but does not return the correct factors. Please help!

```js
function findNumbers(numbers) {
  let factorNumbers = [];
    
  for(i = 1; i < numbers; i++) {
    if(numbers % i === 0) {
      return factorNumbers.push(i);
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: What do you expect that `return factorNumbers.push(i);` will do?

Answer (score 0):

You just pushed the factors in an array. Firstly, you have to add them up and also call the function and console log the result or maybe write an if statement to verify whether this number is a perfect number or not.

```
function findNumbers(number)
    {
    let result = 0;

       for(let i=1; i<=number/2; i++)
         {
             if(number%i === 0)
              {
                result += i;
              }
         }
      console.log(result);
     } 
    findNumbers(6);
```

Comment: Sorry im new to stack overflow, basically this was just part of the function that I console.logged and didnt understand why it wasnt working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check each number up to and equaling the number you pass in to the function, and then return the array *after* the iteration is complete.

```js
function findFactors(number) {
  const factorNumbers = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
    if (number % i === 0) {
      factorNumbers.push(i);
    }
  }
  return factorNumbers;
}

console.log(findFactors(12));
console.log(findFactors(30));
```